# Upsert empty value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to upsert Salesforce data via AMPscript and skip empty values? If our salesforce Lead currently does have a field with a value, and we upsert with empty value, it will be blank. We have to upsert around 20fields, so it would be painful to run 20 single upserts and check if field value is empty. Is there another way?

Comment: Have you looked at the UPSERTDE function?

Comment: I need to upsert SF Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make a http post call using Ampscript with the [UPsert Salesforce API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm).

I would advise using server side java script as it handles arrays better